# Using TabPages in Project Properties window in VisualStudio2012

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012, tabpage

How can I use the Tab control in project properties window in Visual Studio 2012 in my own windows form project?(below picture)

[image]

Comment: It is not a control.  Most of VS is done in WPF.  Not this one, it is done in (drumroll) Winforms.  The "tabs" are actually Button controls.  You can see this by using Spy++.